# How to jump cursor to specific line in visual mode in vi?

Tags: vim, vi

When I am using `vi` I will jump to a new line using `:<line number>`.  And then when I try to highlight something, I will go to visual mode, and try the same command `:<line number>`. but instead of jumping to the line number that I asked, it does some weird behavior.  How do I jump to a specific line while in visual mode?

Answer (score 19):

In visual mode, most movement commands work the same way they do in normal mode. In this case, you can type `<line_number>gg` or `<line_number>G`.

Answer (score 7):

`nG` where `n` is the line number.

Answer (score 1):

In visual mode, you can type the line number you want to go to, then press shift + g to go there.